# How Spring Cloud Stream prevents the application’s instances from receiving duplicate messages?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, idempotent

**Spring Cloud Stream** is based on **At least once** method,This means that in some rare cases a **duplicate message** can arrive at an endpoint.

Does Spring Cloud Stream keep a buffer of already received messages?

The [IdempotentReceiver](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/IdempotentReceiver.html) in Enterprise Integration Patterns book suggests :
Design a receiver to be an Idempotent Receiver,one that can safely receive the same message multiple times.

Does **Spring Cloud Stream** control duplicate messages in consumers?

**Update:**

A paragraph from [Spring Cloud Stream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_main_concepts) says :

> 4.5.1. Durability
>   Consistent with the opinionated application model of Spring Cloud Stream, consumer group subscriptions are durable. That is, a binder implementation ensures that group subscriptions are persistent and that, once at least one subscription for a group has been created, the group receives messages, even if they are sent while all applications in the group are stopped.
>   Anonymous subscriptions are non-durable by nature. For some binder implementations (such as RabbitMQ), it is possible to have non-durable group subscriptions.
>   In general, it is preferable to always specify a consumer group when binding an application to a given destination. When scaling up a Spring Cloud Stream application, you must specify a consumer group for each of its input bindings. **Doing so prevents the application’s instances from receiving duplicate messages** (unless that behavior is desired, which is unusual).

Comment: The above paragraph (4.5.1) applies to "scaling up" applications. When there is more than one instance consuming from the same destination, every instance will receive the all messages, resulting in duplicate processing,  unless the app specifies a consumer group. If a group is specified for the app, one instance receives each message.

Comment: Thanks @dturanski.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your assumption on the responsibility of the spring-cloud-stream framework are incorrect. 
Spring-cloud-stream in a nutshell is a framework responsible for connecting and adapting *producers/consumers* provided by the developer to the message broker(s) exposed by the spring-cloud-stream binder (e.g., Kafka, Rabbit, Kinesis etc). 
So connecting to a broker, receiving message from the broker, deserialising it, invoking user code, serialising message and sending it back to the broker is in the scope of framework responsibility. So you can look at it as purely infrastructure.

What you're describing is more of an application concern since the actual receiver is something that user would develop as part of the spring-cloud-stream development experience, hence responsibility for idempotence would reside with such user.
Also, on top of that most brokers already handle idempotency (in a way) by ensuring that a particular message has been delivered only once. That said, if someone sends identical message to such broker, it will have no idea that it is duplicate so the requirement for idempotency and/or deduplication is still valid, but as you can see it is not as straight forward given the amount of factor that are in play where your understanding of idempotence could be different from mine, hence our approaches could be different as well. 
One last thing (partially to prove my last point): *can safely receive the same message multiple times.* - That is all it states, but what does *safely* really mean to you vs. me vs. some other person?

Comment: Thanks Oleg.I updated the question with a paragraph from document.

Comment: I think parts of the document needs to be reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about a case where the application receives and processes message from the broker but crashes before it acknowledges the message, that can happen. Spring cloud stream app starters provides support for auto-configuration of a persistent [message metadata store](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/core/blob/master/common/app-starters-metadata-store-common/README.adoc) which backs Spring Integration's [IdempotentReceiverInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/handler/advice/IdempotentReceiverInterceptor.html). An example of this is in the [SFTP source app starter](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/sftp/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-sftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/sftp/source/metadata/SftpSourceIdempotentReceiverConfiguration.java). By default, the sftp source uses an in-memory metadata store, so it would not survive a restart, but can be customized to use a persistent store.

Comment: Thanks alot.I'll check your solutions.